# serialize data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I have what I believe is a correct serializing function in Django (1.9) and a file that it writes to, but my function isn't being called. What am I missing?  I've looked for a complete example, but cannot find one.

Here's my function - no errors are being raised, and pdb.set_trace() isn't triggered when in the function. What's the missing step here to writing this data to file?

```
def serialize(request):
    with open("file.json", "w") as out:
        data = serializers.serialize('json', Table.objects.all(), stream=out)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: is this a simple view? maybe you're not setting the correct url for this view

Comment: it is a simple view.  i have no idea what it should be other than that.  any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Why are you returning json_data in the HttpResponse object?

Comment: Mistake. Thanks.  But, now fixed, to be data, like in earlier in the function, and still not getting a data output.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check if the view is being called, to check the content of the data variable and to check the urls.py file to ensure that your view is being called. Currently I can't help you any more. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked:

```
def serialize(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', Meals.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='json')
```

I couldn't get it to write to file, and realized it isn't necessary.  So, win, I suppose.